# Which will result in faster downloading of images?

Tags: image, browser, download

I have a page where a grid is loaded with images. The image url I am supplying to the asp:Image is of the form "../Images/img1.png" .

Now adjacent to the image is a button which pops up a facebook publish dialog with the same image. However, the url I am supplying to facebook JS is http://mydomain.com/Images/img1.png

Now when a user clicks on any of the button for the first time, the dialog does not pop up with the proper values and I just get a loading popup. But from second or third time the dialog pops up without any issues. This behavior has been observed for almost all the testers.

I figured that could be because the image http://mydomain.com/Images/img1.png is not downloaded and cached properly till the second or third request. Though I am not sure.

I was wondering what if I supply http://mydomain.com/Images/img1.png like urls to my grid as well instead of ../Images/img1.png

Will it slow down the image downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering what if I supply
>   http://mydomain.com/Images/img1.png
>   like urls to my grid as well instead
>   of ../Images/img1.png
>
> Will it slow down the image
>   downloading?

simple and short: no